# Postgresql OVER and GROUP

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a problem with grouping

I have a table(a lot more stuff in it, but not relevant) that looks something like:

```
id user
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 2
6 1
7 1
```

I'm trying to get the following value:

```
user start end
1 0 2
2 3 5
1 6 7
```

Basicaly, i need the first and last occurance of user, while not messing with order.
I know i need to use OVER (PARTITION BY ...), But i've never used it and not sure how to build this query.
if i "partition by user", it ignores order. And if i "partition by id, user" it again returns wrong.

Example of what i tried(doesn't even try to get what i need, but is a midpoint that shows me how to do it once i figure out "over" part):

```
SELECT user, count(user) over (partition by user):
user count
1 5
1 5
1 5
2 3
2 3
2 3
1 5
1 5

SELECT user, count(user) over (partition by id, user):
user count
1 1
1 1
1 1
2 1
2 1
2 1
1 1
1 1
```

Comment: `SELECT user, min(id) over (partition by user), max(id)  over (partition by user)` ?..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a difference of row numbers approach to classify consecutive rows with the same user into one group and start over a new group when a new user is encountered. Thereafter, use `group by` to get the start and end of each group.

```
SELECT USER,MIN(ID) AS START,MAX(ID) AS END
FROM (SELECT user,id, row_number() over(order by id) 
                     - row_number() over (partition by user order by id) as grp
      FROM tablename
      ) T
GROUP BY USER,GRP
```

Answer (score 5):

to get start, end of id, use:

```
SELECT user, min(id) over (partition by user) "start", max(id) over (partition by user) "end"
from table_name;
```

**Update**
My answer was based on wrong predicate and so wrong. To provide right one and not duplicate @vkp one, I made this monstrous construct:

```
create table so74 as
select * from (values (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 1), (7, 1)) t(id, u); 

with d as (
    with c as (
        with b as (
            select 
                *
                , case when lag(u) over (order by id) <> u or id = min(id) over() then id end min
                , case when lead(u) over (order by id) <> u or id=max(id) over () then id end max 
            from so74
            )
        select  u, min,max 
        from b 
        where coalesce(min,max) is not null
    ) 
    select u,min,lead(max) over () max  
    from c
) 
select * 
from d 
where coalesce(min,max) is not null
;

 u | min | max
---+-----+-----
 1 |   0 |   2
 2 |   3 |   5
 1 |   6 |   7
(3 rows)

Time: 0.456 ms
```

Comment: To be honest I did not understand your question, I just built a query that will produce your wanted result **I'm trying to get the following value:**. Please update the question if I failed

Comment: The problem is partition will return min and max for each user.

Comment: I see it now! you have user 1 again! - just a min

Comment: @darthzejdr - I updated my answer to have at least working solution for your question

Comment: @vkp approach is much better. I only wanted to justify my upvotes